# kivymd AttributeError: 'MDNavigationDrawer' object has no attribute 'toggle_state'

Tags: python-3.x, kivymd

The example code seems a little outdated, e.g. I had to replace 'NavigationLayout' with 'MDNavigationLayout'.

I'm using the latest kivymd downloaded from [github](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD)

This is [simplest example](https://github.com/attreyabhatt/KivyMD-Basics/blob/master/11%20-%20Navigation%20Drawer/main.py) that I found, but the [example code here](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/navigation-drawer/) has the same issue:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window



Window.size = (300, 500)

navigation_helper = """
Screen:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Navigation Drawer"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                    Widget:
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
"""


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(navigation_helper)
        return screen


DemoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

replacing

```
#left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
```

with

```
left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
```

seems to work

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I just tried, I believe it will work for you.

```
OneLineAvatarListItem:
                    ImageLeftWidget:
                        source: "chorko.jpg"
                        radius: [self.size[1]-(self.size[1]/2)]
```

Try it out..